# I want to create pdf viewer and a widget in one screen

Tags: flutter

I want to create a flutter screen that holds a PDF viewer in half of the screen and in second half set up a widget(text image etc) how i can do this in one screen

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createFileOfPdfUrl().then((f) {
      setState(() {
        pathPDF = f.path;
        print(pathPDF);
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl() async {
    final url = "http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
    final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Plugin example app')),
      body: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(child:
          PDFViewerScaffold(
              path: pathPDF)),
          new FlutterLogo(size: 200.0,)
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to create screen in landscape mode

Comment: Please show some code you have tried and how it fails. Also please note if your problem is related to showing to components in one screen or if it is specific to the pdf viewer you mention.

Comment: please check the code now